# Android application crashing when running on device but works in emulator

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, navigation-drawer

Application was working fine on device I just as main launcher mainactivity was set and was working fine with fragments, but I added 2 fragments which doesn't load before selecting their navigation buttons, the application worked perfectly in emulator and started crashing in device showing this error:

```
02-18 03:04:28.675 3157-3157/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.hscs.ibd.ibdsystem, PID: 3157
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hscs.ibd.ibdsystem/com.hscs.ibd.ibdsystem.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2436)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:631)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(Native Method)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
     at com.hscs.ibd.ibdsystem.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5580)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method) 
     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:631) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(Native Method) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106) 
     at com.hscs.ibd.ibdsystem.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5580) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
  Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f02003f
     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2326)
     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1891)
     at android.content.res.XResources.getDrawable(XResources.java:521)
     at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:321)
     at android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintManager.getDrawable(TintManager.java:145)
     at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:422)
     at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.prepareMenuItems(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:383)
     at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter$NavigationMenuAdapter.<init>(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:255)
     at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.getMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:97)
     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:149)
     at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:88)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method) 
     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:631) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(Native Method) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249) 
     at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106) 
     at com.hscs.ibd.ibdsystem.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5580) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2400) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2495) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:170) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1304) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5635) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

UPDATE:
MainActivity code as below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private boolean loggedIn=false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    Fragment myFragment= new custProductFrag();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content,myFragment)
            .commit();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    loggedIn=sharedPreferences.getBoolean(Config.LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF,false);



    if(loggedIn && sharedPreferences.getString(Config.TYPE_SHARED_PREF,"").equalsIgnoreCase("customer"))
    {
        Intent intent= new Intent(MainActivity.this,drawer.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if(loggedIn && sharedPreferences.getString(Config.TYPE_SHARED_PREF,"admin")=="admin")
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,adminmain.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    Fragment myFragment= new custProductFrag();

    if (id == R.id.nav_products) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_aboutus) {

    }else if (id == R.id.nav_login) {
        myFragment= new Login();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_register) {
        myFragment = new register();

    }

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager= getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content,myFragment)
            .commit();
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Check the code indicated in `at com.hscs.ibd.ibdsystem.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)`

Answer (score 0):

Show your xml
Open the xml and check the preview for any errors

Comment: No error in the preview page, the weird thing is that when i make the older navigationdrawers launcher it works fine, but if I create a new one made it launcher or navigated to it, it crashes even without altering them.